# How do i change the header of my website when you scroll down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want so that when a user scrolls down the header changes its background and the header stays at the top of the window. I don't know if this needs javascript or you can do it in css.

The example of what i want it too look like is at https://anvilnode.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this kind of code

```
html:
<nav id="header_nav">nav here</nav>
```

css:

```
body {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

#header_nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #666;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            },600);
        }
    }
    else {
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small') {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'100px'
        },600);
    }  
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, you need Javascript and CSS
2. Javascript to detect your scroll position and add addtional CSS class to the header component.
3. Using the addional CSS classname add styles to change the background color.

In the same example which you have given, they are adding additional css class 'top-nav-collapse' to the 'nav' component on scroll. You can check this using developer tool.

Comment: Alright i got it, now to figure out how to do that.